Is there a way to get consistent multi-paragraph messages handling on Messages on both iOS and Mac OS
I currently am using iphone and ipad (iOS 17) and MacOS High Sierra and Monterey.
On iOS, return adds a newline.  A separate icon is used to send.
On Mac OS, Return sends the message.  You can get a newline with option-return. shift-return acts as return.
Even the use of option-return is problematic.  Many user interfaces (e.g. facebook, and reddit's web interfaces) allow the use of shift-return to add a line break without sending. Both of those interfaces treat option-return as a return.
I would like the Mac behaviour to be like the iphone behaviour.  I want to have to explicitly send the message.
Since I use messages, reddit and facebook a lot on all three devices, I'd like a solution that does ONE of the following:

Defaults messages on Mac to use return as line break.  Sending the message can be any key combination the developer desires.  Command-Option-Shift-MetaCoffeecup-Down-arrow
Alternative MacOS app that can use Apple's Messages protocol.
Changes Messages on Mac to treat shift-return as line break.


Research:  This is a recurrent question on the Apple Help Community.  There are several mentions of the Option-return workarouond, and some mention of shift-return.
On this site, it comes up in this thread.  It's  only somewhat parallel as the problem is with a bluetooth keyboard on iPad.
How do I disable message sending using the return key on Ipad or Iphone? While using a bluetooth keyboard

On a Mac, I take a simple approach: I compose the message in a text editor and then drag or paste it into Messages. The line breaks are preserved. This would work on a mobile device too, I suppose, but I can't say I've ever bothered to try it.

While this is a workaround, it's not what I'm looking for.  With ADHD ANY time I switch apps is a risk tht I will wander off chasing butterfilies.

I usually use a text editor or note app. It often preserves all the formatting for me. A similar approach to @Linc Davis' comment.
